# How do I make a Standard User the Owner of a Custom Object?

Tags: custom-object, permissions, owner

I've created a custom object and want to make another user the owner, how do I make a Standard User the Owner of a Custom Object?

Error message reads:

> Transfer Requires Read
>   The new owner must have "Read" permissions on this type of record.

Comment: what do you mean by a Standard User? Does it mean a user with Standard User profile? If yes, then you won't be able to edit the Standard User profile, so better clone the profile, edit the permission of custom object to at least READ, and assign new profile to your user.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Permission Set, assign `Read <Object>` to the Permission Set, then assign the Permission Set to the user. Or, you can clone Standard User, assign your Standard User users to the new profile, and add `Read <Object>` to the new profile.